# How to get a appropriate height for a reused cell according to the Label in that cell?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

This is my layout.The Label's top to the ContentView's top is 58pt.The numberOfLine of the Label is 0.So it can Enter automatically.

And I want the Height of every cell is 58.0+10.0+the height of label.

I have tried this code.

`TV.estimatedRowHeight = 68
 TV.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

But didn't work.

And then tried this code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CommentDetailCell
    return 68.0 + cell.Comment.frame.size.height
}
```

Didn't work again.

And then try this!To create a array to store the height of every cell's labelHeight.

`var CommentHeightA:[CGFloat] = [60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0]`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell:CommentDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CommentDetailCell
    cell.UserImg.image = UIImage(named: UserImgA[indexPath.row])
    cell.AtNum.text = AtNumA[indexPath.row]
    cell.LikeNum.text = LikeNumA[indexPath.row]
    cell.isLike.image = UIImage(named: isLikeA[indexPath.row])
    cell.Comment.text = CommentA[indexPath.row]
    CommentHeightA[indexPath.row] = cell.Comment.frame.size.height
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 68.0 + CommentHeightA[indexPath.row]
}
```

And :(  all the ways above is failed.

So how can I get what I want?

Update:

[image]

I have added the bottom constraint and used the 1st way.

This is the result.Only the 1st row has a appropriate height.

[image]

Comment: Please check this : http://natashatherobot.com/ios-8-self-sizing-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-type/ and set your constraints well. check it 2 time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **bottom constraint** from the comment label to the content view. Then add the following code:

```
TV.estimatedRowHeight = 68
TV.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

It will work,

Comment: Are you adding a fixed height constraint to the comment label? I think it's important.

Comment: I have tried. Let me show you by updating the question with screenshots.

Comment: Check my sample project and find out what are you missing. It works for multiple-line UILabel: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn72kdabkdbzqlh/TestAutoLayoutCell.zip?dl=0

Comment: I checked your project.I think it is no difference from urs but the result showed in my question.It is too strange..

Comment: Could you share your project or demo?

Comment: zhangao0086@gmail.com. I shall fix it. :)

Comment: Have u ever found out where the question could be?